# Error al ejecutar archivo Python por consola

Tags: python, selenium, consola, python-import

Al ejecutar un script de Python por consola me da el siguiente error :

```
File "C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\cargaHoras\Tareas\CargarHoras.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Pages.PageLogin import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pages'
```

Al ejecutar el script desde el PyCharm me funciona correcto, pero al querer ejecutarlo por consola me da el error anterior.

Dentro del script tengo definido varios `import` a otras clases Python del proyecto.

¿Cómo hago para poder ejecutar el script por consola?

Estos son los imports del proyecto :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from Pages.PageLogin import *
from Pages.PageMenu import *
from Pages.Page2 import *
from Utilerias.Dominio.Sistema import *
```

Comment: Parece que en *PyCharm* estás utilizando un *virtualenv* en el que está instalado el módulo *Pages*, pero en tu instalación de *Python* no está instalado. Si no es eso es que estás utilizando dos versiones de *Python* distintas. Puede que estés utilizando la distribución *Anaconda* al ejecutar tu programa desde *PyCharm*. Prueba a instalar/reinstalar el módulo *Pages* desde consola con *pip*. Un saludo.

Comment: Al intentar importar el modulo Pages me esta dando este error :ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pages (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pages.

Comment: Que tienes en el __init__.py del proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

Debes configurar la varaible `PYTHONPATH` con el directorio donde están las bibliotecas y los ficheros .py de tu proyecto, por ejemplo, asumiendo que tienes las dependencias en un directorio `/lib` dentro de la carpeta con tu proyecto, sería algo como esto:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\cargaHoras\Tareas;C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\cargaHoras\Tareas\lib
python3 CargarHoras.py
```

Si la ruta donde está el módulo `Pages` es distinta entonces añade el directorio que lo contiene correspondiente a la variable `PYTHONPATH`

Otra opción (quizás más genérica) es usar rutas relativas en `PYTHONPATH`:

```
cd C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\cargaHoras\Tareas
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;.;.\lib
python3 CargarHoras.py
```

Para más información:

- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH
- https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables